# How to add an extra onChange method into Formik's field?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, formik

I have been trying to add an extra onChange event which is a simple state change to count character limits but when I add it into my Input tag, it overrides the Formik default onChange.

Does anyone know how to add an extra event without overriding it?

```
    const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
```

What I want to add to the onChange

```
onChange={(e) => setCount(count - e.target.value.length)}
```

```
{(props) => (
  <Form>
    <Box mt="25px">
      <Field name="title" validate={validateTitle}>
        {({ field, form }) => (
          // console.log("test", { ...field })
          // console.log(field.onChange)
          <FormControl
            alignSelf="baseline"
            isInvalid={form.errors.title && form.touched.title}
            isRequired
          >
            <FormLabel>Title</FormLabel>
            <Input {...field} />
            <FormErrorMessage>{form.errors.title}</FormErrorMessage>
          </FormControl>
        )}
      </Field>
    </Box>
  </Form>
)}
```

Comment: You can try using `onInput` instead

Comment: An event listener may what you looking for , Or call the the second function instead the first onchange function ?(is alternative and ugly solution but well)